# Akka-HTTP how map JSON entity with two case class in single REST call

Tags: json, scala, rest, akka-http

I am trying to map `JSON` with more than one case class in single POST call

```
 val route = (path(HttpConstants.CreateJob) & post) {
    entity(as[JobDetailsEntity]) {
      jobDetailsEntity: JobDetailsEntity =>
      complete(createJobDetails(updatedJobDetailsEntity).map(_.asJson))
      } ~
      entity(as[JobEntity]) { jobEntity: JobEntity =>
       complete(createJob(updatedJobEntity).map(_.asJson))
     }
  }
```

Doing so only executes `createJobDetails` and not `createJob`.

```
case class JobDetailsEntity(id:Option[Long],name:String,data:String,createDate:Long)

case class JobEntity(id:Option[Long],name:String,createDate:Long)
```

Although it works if I do this in separate POST calls with different Route path. Help me out if there is way to do this in single REST call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `~` (or `concat`) you [concatenate 2 routes](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/10.0.6/scala/http/routing-dsl/routes.html#composing-routes), essentially making the second a fallback for the first, in case the first does not complete successfully.

What you are looking for is an equivalent of nesting your directives in a single route. You can use `&` (as you already did on directives `path` and `post`) to achieve this result.

```
 val route = (path(HttpConstants.CreateJob) & post) {
    (entity(as[JobDetailsEntity]) & entity(as[JobEntity])) {
      (jobDetailsEntity: JobDetailsEntity, jobEntity: JobEntity) =>
      complete(...)
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Either can help here. Use as following:

```
post {
      entity(as[Either[JobDetailsEntity, JobEntity]]) {
        case left: Left[JobDetailsEntity, JobEntity] => doSomethingWith(left.value)
        case right: Right[JobDetailsEntity, JobEntity] => doSomethingWith(right.value)
      }
    }
```